# Find duplicate rows in excel across columns containing blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to flag duplicate rows across 5 columns in excel which also has some blank fields

The usual countif formula isn't giving me the desired result as I believe it is not taking into account the blanks

```
     A B C D E
     1   2 1 2 .  -duplicate
     0     1 3
     1   2 1 2 . -duplicate
     0     1 2
```

The formula given here does not work for me [Excel array formula to find duplicate row across multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930265/excel-array-formula-to-find-duplicate-row-across-multiple-columns])

Comment: What version of Excel are you using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using the same helper column method on the accepted answer I would use something to denote the cells like `|`

In F1:

```
=A1&"|"&B1&"|"&C1&"|"&D1&"|"&E1&"|"
```

Then the countif:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(F:F,F1)>1,"Duplicate","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a CONCAT formula to see if there are duplicated values, even if there are blank cells this still works as long as the blanks are located in the same column.

=CONCAT(A2:E2)

You can apply conditional formatting to the column where you added the CONCAT formula and highlight all duplicate cells.

[This is the end result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88wuL.png)

Comment: You will get false positive if in row 4 you put 1 in A, 2 in B, blank in C, 1 in D and 2 in E.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following formula and if it returns `TRUE` it means it is duplicated:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--EXACT(A1&B1&C1&D1&E1,A$1:$A$11&B$1:$B$11&C$1:$C$11&D$1:$D$11&E$1:$E$11))>1
```

Replace the ranges in the second part of the **EXACT** formula (`A$1:A$11`,`B$1:B$11`,`C$1:C$11` etc.) with the relevant ranges on your worksheet.

Please note I have added a few sample data to test the formula and it is **case sensitive**. If you do not require a case sensitive match, use the following instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1&B1&C1&D1&E1=A$1:$A$11&B$1:$B$11&C$1:$C$11&D$1:$D$11&E$1:$E$11))>1
```

[image: Answer]

Cheers :)